# backbone layout manager after render

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-layout-manager

I am using Backbone and Layout Manager. I have this code inside MyView.js:

```
afterRender: function() {
    var scope = this;
    this.model.get("books").each(function(bookModel) {
            var bookView = new BookView({
                model: bookModel
            });
            scope.insertView(".books", bookView).render();
    });
},
```

Inside BookView.js I have afterRender method:

```
afterRender: function() {
    console.log("after render");
},
```

I have 6 items in the books property of the model and I call `render()` for each book. Eventually what I get is "after render" logged only once. What is wrong? Where are the missing 5 "after render" logs??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above was invoking inside MyView's afterRender method. For unknown reasons many calls to `render()` one by one don't invoke  each book's afterRender().
After reading again and again in the LayoutManager documentation I realized that I need to call `insertView()` inside the `beforeRender()` method without rendering the views. This way `render()` will render all the sub-views and `afterRender()` will invoked properly:

```
beforeRender: function() {
    var scope = this;
    this.model.get("books").each(function(bookModel) {
            var bookView = new BookView({
                model: bookModel
            });
            scope.insertView(".books", bookView);
    });
},
```